# Any way to access azure blob storage through the management APIs?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

I'm already authenticated to Azure via AAD (Client ID and Client Secret) using their management Apis. I need to delete some stuff from the blob storage, which I know the name (but not the key at this stage) Is this possible to use the same access token that I got from the Resource Manager API to access and delete the blobs, or do I need to use the Blob Storage Key?

Comment: You would need to use Storage REST API as Resource Manager API is for managing the control plane (managing storage accounts themselves) only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this official page for all the storage account blob rest apis

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/blob-service-rest-api